# How to activate a given cell in Excel using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to Activate a given cell (say A29) using VBScript.

I tried:

```
xlsobj.WorkBooks.Open("abcd.xlsx").range("A29").activate
```

but it didn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify/access the sheet:

```
xlsobj.WorkBooks.Open("abcd.xlsx").sheets("...").range("A29").activate
```

Note the added `.Sheets("...")` bit where you must replace `...` with the actual name of your sheet.

Comment: I used the above logic of selecting the sheet and then activating, but it didn't worked, I am doing this in **vbscript** it is bydefault selecting A1 cell only

Comment: @Arpit - "does not work" does not work as a description of a problem. You need to be more specific: error messages? actual vs expected behaviour/results?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a range of a workbook. You need to specify a worksheet.

So something more like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A29").Activate
```

Comment: There is no plain "ActiveWorkBook" when automating Excel from a VBScript script.

Comment: I used the above logic of selecting the sheet and then activating, but it didn't worked, I am doing this in **vbscript**

it is bydefault selecting A1 cell only